# kivy buildozer error - Error compiling Cython file

Tags: python, kivy

I am building the kivy app using buildozer,

`buildozer android debug deploy run` for this command, i got this error -

```
kivy/core/image/_img_sdl2.pyx:35:18: Cannot assign type 'size_t (*)(SDL_RWops *, const void *, size_t, size_t) except? -1' to 'size_t (*)(SDL_RWops *, void *, size_t, size_t) noexcept'. Exception values are incompatible. Suggest adding 'noexcept' to type 'size_t (SDL_RWops *, const void *, size_t, size_t) except? -1'.
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    cdef SDL_RWops *rwops = SDL_AllocRW()
    rwops.hidden.unknown.data1 = <void *>byteio
    rwops.seek = NULL
    rwops.read = NULL
    rwops.write = &rwops_bytesio_write
    rwops.close =&rwops_bytesio_close
                 ^
------------------------------------------------------------
kivy/core/image/_img_sdl2.pyx:36:17: Cannot assign type 'int (*)(SDL_RWops *) except? -1' to 'int (*)(SDL_RWops *) noexcept'. Exception values are incompatible. Suggest adding 'noexcept' to type 'int (SDL_RWops *) except? -1'.
  STDERR:
# Command failed: ['/home/vishakraj/Documents/app/app_env/bin/python', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'create', '--dist_name=dynamic_app', '--bootstrap=sdl2', '--requirements=python3,cython,pyjnius,kivy', '--arch=arm64-v8a', '--arch=armeabi-v7a', '--copy-libs', '--color=always', '--storage-dir=/home/vishakraj/Documents/app/app_test_1/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a', '--ndk-api=21', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug']
```

versions:
Python - 3.10.12
kivy  - 2.2.1
pyjnius - 1.6.1
cython - 3.0.5

What this error means, and how to solve it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

This error states the issue is in the Cython version, as mentioned in [the documentation](https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html), Cython version has to be `0.29.33`.

```bash
pip3 install --user --upgrade Cython==0.29.33
```

Comment: Is this answered your question? Please accept it as an answer by clicking on the check mark icon on the left.

Comment: @thedemons, yes it is answered my question, i give this answer as the accepted answer, but i got the message from stackoverflow that i have to wait for two days to make this answer as the accepted answer for this quesetion